# Asp.Net - Server Tag Not Well Formed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on debugging a website and I'm stuck on this section of code. I'm connecting the site to a current database and I keep getting this error message no matter what I try. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Error is happening with Line 129.

> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

```
Line 127:</asp:SqlDataSource>
Line 128:
Line 129:<asp:SqlDataSource> ID="SqlDataEQ11" <asp:Literal runat="server" Text"<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnLocation %>" > </>  
Line 130:    database="ConnectionStrings" Integrated Security=True <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnLocation.ProviderName %>"> </>
Line 131: SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT EQ11
```

Comment: Check "" in ID . Should be ID="SqlDataEQ11" .

Comment: The code as it appears in the error message has so many problems I am not sure it is displayed correctly. Can you post the real code from your aspx file?

Answer (score 2):

I see an extra quote.

```
ID="SqlDataEQ11" " >
                 ^
```